How to create child process to init? (process with PPID 1)
I'm currently exploring process management on Linux systems and came across an interesting question: How can one create a child process directly linked to the init process, which typically has a PPID (Parent Process ID) of 1?

Actually the init system has a PID of 1. It is correct that the PPID (parent) is 0, but that is the kernel starting the init system. So the PPID is not really relevant here, it's more relevant that init is PID 1.

There are several ways to create child processes to the Init system - which on Ubuntu is systemd, and has the PID 1 (Lennart Poettering's blog is called Pid Eins).
Basically, all daemons you start will be a child proces of /sbin/init,  and thus have PPID 1. This goes for:

Daemons startet with systemctl or snap (on my system, this is the case for docker, smbd etc.)
Daemons startet from cron on @reboot (on my system, this the case for sshfs)
Daemons startet from .bashrc on login (on my system, this is the case for tmux)

In addition, orphaned processes will be "taken over" by the init system, and will also have PPID 1.
This is very visible with htop in tree view:


I want to add that the orphan process will also receive the parent process init, thank you for answer.

You can match processes by PPID directly with pgrep ex. pgrep -aP1
